# Javascript Case Sensitive filter not working

Tags: javascript

i'm using script below, the search is case sensitive not working.

```js
(function($){
 $.fn.tableSearch = function(options){
  if(!$(this).is('table')){
   return;
  }
  var tableObj = $(this),
   divObj = $('<label>Search: </label>'),
   inputObj = $('<input class="form-control" type="text" />');
  inputObj.off('keyup').on('keyup', function(){ var searchFieldVal = $(this).val();
   tableObj.find('tbody tr').hide().each(function(){ var currentRow = $(this);
    currentRow.find('td').each(function(){
     if($(this).html().indexOf(searchFieldVal)>-1){
      currentRow.show();
      return true;
     }
    });
   });
  });
  tableObj.before(divObj.append(inputObj));
 }
}(jQuery));
```

How would I go about making it non-case sensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your search term and your text value lowercase:

`if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFieldVal.toLowerCase()) > -1) { ... }`